# in mysql, weird results when dropping / adding users

Tags: mysql, security, permissions

have a security routine that, from an array of user names, passwords and permissions

- drops a user
- creates the (same) user
- grants access to tables, procedures, etc

```
// $users - Array of user records
// $tables - list of tables from `show tables`

// create users as necessary, reset password
foreach( $users as $user=>$arr ) {
        mysql_query( "drop user {$arr['user']}" );
        mysql_query( "create user {$arr['user']} identified by '{$arr['pwd']}'" );
};

// for each user set permission
foreach( $users as $user=>$arr ) {
     if( @$arr['table_grant'] ) foreach( $tables as $table )
        mysql_query( "grant {$arr['table_grant']} on $table to {$arr['user']}" );
     if( @$arr['tables_revoke'] ) foreach( $arr['tables_revoke'] as $table )                
        mysql_query( "revoke {$arr['table_grant']} on $table from {$arr['user']}" );
     if( @$arr['procedures_grant'] ) foreach( $arr['procedures_grant'] as $proc 
        mysql_query( "grant execute on procedure $proc to {$arr['user']}" );
     if( @$arr['functions_grant'] ) foreach( $arr['functions_grant'] as $func )
        mysql_query( "grant execute on function $func to {$arr['user']}" );
}
```

If no users exist, it works fine.

If users already exist, the user is there, but *without the password* for all but the last user created.

```
mysql> select user, password from mysql.user where user like 'm%';
+------------+-------------------------------------------+
| user       | password                                  |
+------------+-------------------------------------------+
| massage150 | *21A196706D99436A1C8163A98AE0687C432C37E2 |
| mlogin     | *DE069F0ED7E311D173CB01C3DD136D282E66048D |
| mselect    |                                           |
| mdml       |                                           |
+------------+-------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Is there some sort of `sync` process that needs to be run in `MySQL` when working with users and permission?  Do I need to delete them, wait a few seconds, and recreate?  Or what?

(Code works fine in postgreSQL and Oracle.  Some modifications were made for MySQL's limitations with GRANT and REVOKE, viz, GRANT was made on a table by table basis (instead of SCHEMA wide) so the subsequently issued REVOKE would work correctly.)

---

#### KLUDGE Solution

After setting GRANTs and REVOKEs for users, make one more pass through the users and `SET PASSWORD`.  Ugly, but it works.

Still looking for better understanding of what's going on.

#### Correct KLUDGE Solution

As per answer below (thanks!) MySQL has a non-ANSI command FLUSH PRIVILEGES.  Issued this after DROP USER and before CREATE USER and MySQL no longer dropped user password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing a FLUSH PRIVILEGES after the CREATE USER statements. Per the docs:

> The server caches information in memory as a result of GRANT and
>   CREATE USER statements. This memory is not released by the
>   corresponding REVOKE and DROP USER statements, so for a server that
>   executes many instances of the statements that cause caching, there
>   will be an increase in memory use. This cached memory can be freed
>   with FLUSH PRIVILEGES.

Worth a shot. I've noticed updates to the users table does not directly take effect without running this command.

Comment: put it after DROP USER and before CREATE USER - works fine! - thanks - not your problem at all, still reserve the right to bitch about having to use non-standard SQL to make things simply work in MySQL.